# ¿Se puede ocultar bases de datos a usuarios específicos?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la versión 4.7.4 de PhpMyAdmin y quisiera saber si se puede ocultar bases de datos a usuarios con menos privilegios, ya que tengo mi usuario root@localhost y en conecta con la BBDD solo cuando en mi sistema es superadmin, ahora bien, estoy haciendo otro nivel de usuario que no tenga todos los privilegios root, pero quisiera saber si a ese usuario se le pueden ocultar BBDD que no quiero que vea.

No puede crear bases de datos, pero si puede ver la información de ellas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: crea un usuario y dale permisos a la base de datos que puede ver

Answer (score -1):

Creo que si le quitas privilegios con GRANT a esos usuarios nuevos se podría asemejar a lo que pides, échale un vistazo a esto https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Esa documentación es para SQLServer